# 'hidden_cursor()' not setting visibility on exit

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python script using Blessed and can't get the 'hidden_cursor()' function to work properly.

It will successfully hide the cursor but it won't set the visibility back on exit.

This is what I tried so far:

```
with term.hidden_cursor():
    while True:
        command = raw_input (term.move(27, 2) + "")
        if command == "X":
            os.system('clear')
            sys.exit()
        else:
            os.system('clear')
            main('self')
```

And here's the full script: https://gist.github.com/lovemac15/c5e71e0b8aa428693e5b

Thanks! :D

Comment: Please provide a Minimum Compilable Example, not just a link to a whole lot of code.

Comment: @Caridorc I was editing the post as you commented. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying, it will be much easier to fix the problem

Comment: @Caridorc thank you for taking the time to help me with this issue! :D

Comment: From the interactive shell the cursor goes back to normal after running...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the control flow to be sure to exit the `with` block:

```
with term.hidden_cursor():
    while True:
        command = raw_input (term.move(27, 2) + "")
        if command == "X":
            os.system('clear')
            sys.exit()
        else:
            os.system('clear')
            break
main('self')
```

Comment: Except it's only supposed to exit if the user types X, anything else should go to "main('self')".

Comment: @JohnLisboa I see, have You tried putting the with block inside the loop and not outsider?